# A lot of Internet Explorer background processes

Tags: windows-8

I don't know where they are from, but there are around **100** Internet Explorer processes running at all times (background processes). I do ***NOT*** use Internet explorer.

[image]

Any reason for it? It annoys me a little

Comment: Do they come back if you kill them?

Comment: Not as far as I've tried

Comment: There are lots of applications that use the IE engine.  What other applications do you have open?

Comment: Google talk, Firefox, Skype, Eclipse, uTorrent, Dropbox... But a few of those IE processes reopened after a while